# List of GUI Frameworks good idea?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I've spent quite a few hours over the past year or so searching for GUI frameworks that fit my particular needs for various projects. Most searches end up on stackoverflow, and I do learn a lot from the answers there, but the posts are quite outdated.

Would it be a good idea to maintain a community wiki with a list of popular GUI frameworks and a summary of their features? Maybe even different lists for popular OSs and one for cross platform GUI frameworks? I agree it doesn't conform perfectly to current moderation guidelines, but there is no doubt that it would be useful, if done properly.

Comment: Sure, fine idea, but **not on Stack Overflow**. Wikipedia already has [such lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_widget_toolkits), for example. Such lists are firmly *off-topic* for the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Except in tagwikis.

Comment: @Manishearth: If the topic is 'calm' enough to avoid edit wars, perhaps a tag wiki is a suitable place. But not many people actually look at those, so the info is likely to go stale.

Comment: I don't see why I'm getting so many downvotes for the question itself. Fine, the answer is "no, it's a very bad idea", but does that make my question **on meta** itself horribly wrong?

Comment: @VivekGhaisas: votes are different on meta; they're often used to indicate disagreement with the post, not that the post is horribly wrong.

Comment: @Wooble Oh, ok. We learn something new every day, don't we?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, [Community Wiki is dead](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/). Posting such a question would get it immediately closed as "not constructive".

However, you can coordinate an effort to collaboratively add this list to the [gui](/questions/tagged/gui) [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/gui/info). Such lists do well in tag wikis.

Comment: Fair enough. I'll look into tag wikis. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No, we have decided ages ago (and discussed ad infinitum), that shopping lists *are not a good fit* for the Stack Exchange network.

Leave such lists to sites that *do* want to handle them. Wikipedia for example, already [has a list of toolkits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_widget_toolkits).